# Como le puedo hacer para que todo lo que haya en un parrafo de un archivo txt se pase a una sola linea en java

Tags: java, txt

```
public class leer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileReader fr= new FileReader("Downloads\\file.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String cadena;
    

            while((cadena= br.readLine()) != null){ 
                System.out.println(""+cadena);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Primero leo el archivo txt
por ejemplo del 1 al 4 es un parrafo y del 5 al 8 otro

1. dia
2. mes
3. año
4. nombre
5. 08
6. 07
7. 1984
8. monica

y que se pase de esta manera

1. dia mes año nombre
2. 08 07 1984 monica

Comment: ¿No has intentado nada? Fomentamos el aprendizaje. Lo que quiere decir que esperamos que hayas hecho algo aunque hayas fallado antes de darte el código que haga lo que esperas.

Comment: ha si claro lo primero que hago es leer el archivo y se que de ahi tengo que realizar una parte con arreglos pero ahi es donde me estoy atorando
public class leer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileReader fr= new FileReader("hola.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String cadena;
    

            while((cadena= br.readLine()) != null){ 
                System.out.println(""+cadena);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion en la pregunta...

Comment: Usa `print` en lugar de `println` e imprime un salto de línea cada cuatro líneas leídas.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar FileWriter tambien funciona, pero ya que había leído el archivo con Files.read... también lo aplique para volver a escribirlo.

1. Se leen los bytes del archivo con Files.readAllBytes
2. Se construye un String a partir de esos bytes
3. Se separan las palabras a partir del salto de linea, usando split
4. El for va recorriendo todas las palabras del arreglo y cuando las palabras recorridas es igual al tamaño de palabras de un párrafo se crea un salto de linea para construir el siguiente párrafo, mientras tanto se van anidando las palabras con un espacio.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()); 
    
    String text = new String(bytes);

    String[] split = text.split("\\r?\\n|\\r");
    
    text = "";
    
    int cadaCuandoParrafo = 4; // cada n palabras es un párrafo
    int recorrido = 0; // palabras recorridas
    
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if(recorrido < cadaCuandoParrafo) {
            text += split[i] + " ";
            recorrido++;
        }
        if(recorrido == cadaCuandoParrafo) {
            text += "\n";
            recorrido = 0;
        }
    }
    
    Files.write(file.toPath(), text.getBytes());
}
```

Con FileWriter para escribir devuelta el texto:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(text);
writer.close();
```

El archivo:

```
dia
mes
año
nombre
08
07
1984
monica
```

Al ejecutar el archivo se reescribe de esta manera:

```
dia mes año nombre 
08 07 1984 monica
```

Si el archivo tiene varios altos de linea entre las palabras, es cuestión de ir ajustando la variable `cadaCuandoParrafo`